EAS/Expo/ReactNative Android build fails androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01
I am using Expo Managed Workflow for React native.
When I am building for Android, its fails with this error :
I have tried many things but it always crash, I dont know if its a version issue with one of my packages..
> Task :react-native-screens:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:
     
       1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.15.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 35 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :app is currently compiled against android-34.
     
           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
           plugin 8.2.1 is 34.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
           plugin to one that supports 35, then update this project to use
           compileSdk of at least 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 7m 32s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

Here is my app.json file :
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "***",
    "slug": "***",
    "version": "1.0.24",
    "sdkVersion": "51.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/lotyicon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/lotygif.gif",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "***",
      "buildNumber": "19",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Nous avons besoin de votre localisation pour afficher les boutiques autour de vous.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Nous avons besoin de votre localisation pour afficher les boutiques autour de vous."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/lotyicon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "***",
      "googleServicesFile": "google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 24,
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "***"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/lotyicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "***"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-font",
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Nous avons besoin de la caméra pour scanner les QR Code des boutiques."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Nous avons besoin de votre localisation pour afficher les boutiques autour de vous."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}


And here is my package.json :
{
  "name": "lotyproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adrianso/react-native-device-brightness": "^1.2.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.5",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~8.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.3.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.14",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.6",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.11",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-animated-placeholder-textinput": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-drop-shadow": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-table": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screen-brightness": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "typed-async-storage": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


I tried to go to SDK 35 with expo-build-properties but then my build crashes with this error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details


What is the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) version you are using? Since you upgraded to API 35, you might need to upgrade that too.

From this line "Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle plugin 8.2.1 is 34."  I think I am using 8.2.1 but I dont know how to change it for a managed workflow

Please share your build.gradle files

EDIT :
I removed react-native-brightness package, I dont know why but it was the one causing the issue.
